# Show that following series is uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{kx} = e^x+e^{2x}+\cdots$$ is uniformly convergent for $|x|<\frac14.$

I tried something like:

We have the $n$th partial sum as a function, $$S_n(x)= \sum_{r=1}^n e^{rx}$$

and so $$S_n(x)=\frac{e^x(1-e^{nx})}{1-e^x}.$$

Now, $$S(x)= \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n(x)=\frac {e^x}{1-e^x}$$ when $x\ne 0$ and when $x=0$ then $S(x)=1$.

Let for given $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N$ such that $|S_n(x)-S(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. We obtain $\left|\frac{e^x}{1-e^x} (-e^{nx})\right|$
here.. How can I proceed or some other way to solve?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: $e^{nx}$ becomes infinite for all $x\gt 0$ as $n\to \infty$.   Your limit statement is WRONG!

Answer (score 2):

This series doesn't pass the divergence test.  The individual terms don't go to zero.  $e^{rx}\stackrel{r\to\infty}\to \infty $, for $0\lt x\lt\dfrac 14$.  So the series diverges.